# Using Mongoose and Expressjs to create an API on localhost and fetch it from front end

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, webforms

So I have an API that connects to Mongodb and is normally able to add data using services such as postman. However when I go try to do the same thing using a webform instead there is a 400 error saying that it was a bad request as a result my data from the web form does not even reach my API. My API is running on Localhost and my front end is running locally just by opening the html file.

Something to notice my schema for mongoose is only
{
name:String
}
there is some extra info but they are set to default adn they are not required

```
const formin = document.getElementById('form-not-click')

form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    const payload = new FormData(formin)

    const sendData = {
        name : 'yyyyy'
    }
    console.log([...payload])

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/customer',{
        method:"POST",
        mode:"no-cors",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id:'',
            name : 'yyymsdcyy'})
    }).then(res =>res.json).then(data =>console.log(data)).catch(err =>console.log(err))
})
```

this is my fetch rquest to my api running oinlocalhost port 3000

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a couple of potential issues with your code that could be causing the 400 Bad Request error:

1. **No-CORS Mode**: You are setting the mode to "no-cors" in your fetch request. This mode is used when making requests to a different origin, but it restricts the information returned in the response. However, in your case, both your frontend and backend are running on localhost, so you shouldn't need to use "no-cors" mode.
2. **FormData Usage**: You are creating a FormData object from your form (`formin`), but you're not actually using it in your fetch request. Instead, you're sending a hardcoded JSON object. You should use the FormData object to send the form data.

Here's how you can update your code:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form-not-click');

form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(form);
    const sendData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/customer', {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(sendData),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

With these changes, your frontend should correctly send the form data to your API, and you should be able to debug any issues related to the 400 Bad Request error. Make sure to check your backend logs for more information on why the request is failing.